# how perform click if image is background imgage of li element?

Tags: jquery, html

I have html like this :

```
<li id="lielement">
<span>Descriptions</span>
</li>
```

and css like this :

```
#divBtnList li {
    background-color: #BEBDBE;
    background-image: url("../Images/RemoveButton.ico");
    background-position: 100% 25%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000000;
    color: #7F7F7F;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',HelveticaNeue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 3px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px;
}
```

i got a problem that, i need to click on `Removebutton` and also click on `Descriptions`
how could i write jquery event?

html is here : http://jsfiddle.net/BLYg3/

```
1 - i want to click  event for Descriptions
2-  i want to click event for background image
```

Could you help me please

Comment: which version of jquery?

Comment: Can you post the entire related HTML markup too?

Comment: The jQuery isn't actually 1.7.2. It is 1.9.1 You're using the min. versoin of latest jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

First off, assuming you're using the most up to date jQuery you shouldn't be using `live` instead use`on`. `live` is now deprecated as of 1.7 and you will need to include a graceful update file from jQuery to use this function as of 1.9.

```
 $("#someelement").on("click", 'li', function (e) {
```

I'll edit my answer once you've given a little more information on the markup.

Comment: It's jQuery 1.7.1; so it isn't the error from `live` and `on`.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For readability and maintainability sake use the right elements for the right objectives, in this case you should use an <a> element or a <button> element.

Also, live is deprecated, use

```
// Feel free to replace document with a "closer" parent selector
$(document).on("click", ".ClassName span", function (e) {
  // ...
});
```

And finally, so long as none of your event handlers has a "return false" or "stopPropagation" then the event should bubble up and both handlers should be triggered.

Comment: It's jQuery 1.7.1; so it isn't the error from `live` and `on`.

Comment: that part was a suggestion, the part about "return false" and "stopPropagation" was a best guess on where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

An example of what you want:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#description").click(function(){
            alert("Description Clicked");
        });

        $("#remove").click(function(){
            alert("Remove Button Clicked");
        });
    });

<a href="#" id="description">Description</a>
<a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kwgtf/